# Generic Solutions to the Coupon Collector Problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Suppose I wanted to find out how many rolls it would take to get 75% of the values on a N sided dice, how would I do this?

Comment: just truncate the standard method for solving the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Do you mean the *expected* number of rolls to get $75\%$ of the values?